# How can I change extends of a php class?

Tags: php, oop

In fact, I have a class that has a extends and I do not want to edit class directly, Is it possible to change a class extends in PHP?
For example I have a class like:

```
class FirstClass extends SecondClass
```

I want to override it to:

```
class FirstClass extends Myclass
```

How can I change it without edit it directly?

Comment: By **extending** a class you are somehow **inheriting** the methods and attributes of a class. In your example **FirstClass** would inherit from the other classes. So, if **MyClass** is the base class **FirstClass** can be a specialization of MyClass and does not change anything of MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if this can be changed without changing the code, it's not possible. There isn't a function to change the extends of the class.

You could change the content of the class it extends. If you make the content of the SecondClass, to the content of MyClass, that will work.

Comment: Thanks, however how can I override `SecondClass` without  edit it ?

Comment: You can't change the code without editing the code? If your Firstclass is in one file you can't edit, and that extends SecondClass, in a file you can edit, you need to edit the content of SecondClass to be the content you want. You can't change the content of a file, without actually changing the content.